# Bootstrap form not displaying properly in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a custom form using Bootstrap and have been unsuccessful in making it show up properly in Firefox - it works in every other browser. For some reason its kicking the radio buttons off the edge of the page and won't display them within the div I set for them. The strange thing is the actual form works - I can input my selections and it does what it is supposed to do. It just isn't in the right spot.

The form can be viewed here (on Firefox) - http://goo.gl/cWXPfk

Comment: What radio buttons? All I see is that select sized to about 750 pixels wide hanging off the right side.

Comment: Nobody wants to visit your site and hunt around for your problems, homie. Can you demonstrate the issue in an isolated jsfiddle? If it's only occurring on your site, than you're basically asking us to debug your actual page instead of showing any understanding of the underlying code.

Comment: Never used stackoverflow before and pretty new at anything besides HTML and CSS. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this in that "span8" container below the "Contact Us" header:

```
<div class="span8">
  <div id="successmessage"> </div>
</div>
```

That's confusing the layout engine. I don't think you want that element to have the "span8" class; it's already inside a "span8" container.

If you take the class off that element, the layout works.